# Retrieving the COM Class factory in IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, com, iis-7

I have an **32-bit COM+ Application**. One instance taking about 200MB~ in memory. I'm using this COM-object in my ASP.NET MVC 4 Web-Application. **Web-Application is 32-bit too**.

It's works good enough at Debugging and at IIS 7. Problems starts when I need to create 5 and more COM instances simultaneously: it's works fine at Debugging (with IIS express. I tried about 100 instances and it worked fine too), but crashes after publish at IIS 7.

IIS 7 configs:

1. "Enable 32-Bit Applications": true
2. "Identity": LocalSystem
3. "Pipeline mode": I tried classic and integrated

Web-app identity: use app pool identity (LocalSystem).

Authorization: Anonymous - use app pool indetity (LocalSystem)

In Web-App log: **Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {AppID} failed due to the following error: 80080005. HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE).**

Looks like it not due the access reasons. It possible to create COM-object at IIS 7, but not possible to create a lot of them simultaneously.

In COM-application log I see this: **Out of system resource**. So, looks like the reason is memory can't be allocated at heap. But it can be allocated when works in IIS Express.

I thought that COM+ Application is always out-of-process, like this:

[image: COM obj memory area in Web-APP 1]

But could it be inprocess like this, while hosting at IIS7?

[image: COM obj memory area in Web-APP 2]

Is it possible to fix this issue?

My OS: Windows 7 x64.

Comment: COM+ hosted apps will always be out of process. Does the app fail immediately? Did you make sure that you configured the correct launch and activation permissions for the site's anonymous user in your COM+ app?

Comment: @Kev Web-app works fine at IIS 7 with 1-4 COM - objects. Permissions are looks correct. I think, if reason are permissions, then I'll get 80070005 (Access denied) error code?